# System.Threading.Timer keep reference to it

Tags: c#, reference, timer, dispose

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx][1] you need to keep a reference to a System.Threading.Timer to prevent it from being disposed.

I've got a method like this:

```
private void Delay(Action action, Int32 ms)
    {
        if (ms <= 0)
        {
            action();
        }

        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            (o) => action(), 
            null, 
            ms, 
            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Which I don't think keeps a reference to the timer, I've not seen any problems so far, but that's probably because the delay periods used have been pretty small.

Is the code above wrong? And if it is, how to I keep a reference to the Timer? I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
    class timerstate 
    {
        internal volatile System.Threading.Timer Timer;
    };

    private void Delay2(Action action, Int32 ms)
    {
        if (ms <= 0)
        {
            action();
        }


        timerstate state = new timerstate();
        lock (state)
        {
            state.Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                (o) => 
                { 
                    lock (o) 
                    { 
                        action();
                        ((timerstate)o).Timer.Dispose();
                    } 
                },
                state,
                ms,
                System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

The locking business is so I can get the timer into the timerstate class before the delegate gets invoked. It all looks a little clunky to me. Perhaps I should regard the chance of the timer firing before it's finished constructing and assigned to the property in the timerstace instance as negligible and leave the locking out.

Comment: By wiring the action event to it, it should keep from getting disposed. That would be my guess why you haven't had a problem with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Thinking about your problem a bit more generally, I think what you're actually trying to accomplish here is achievable in a much simpler way, without using a `System.Threading.Timer` at all.

Is this basically what you want your method to do? Perform `action` after a specified number of milliseconds? If so, I would suggest something like the following alternative implementation instead:

```
private void Delay(Action action, int ms)
{
    if (ms <= 0)
    {
        action();
        return;
    }

    System.Threading.WaitCallback delayed = state =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);
        action();
    };

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delayed);
}
```

...by the way, are you aware that in the code you posted, specifying a non-zero value for `ms` will cause `action` to be executed twice?

---

### Original Answer

The `timerstate` class really isn't necessary. Just add a `System.Threading.Timer` member to whatever class contains your `Delay` method; then your code should look like this:

```
public class Delayer
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    private void Delay(Action action, Int32 ms)
    {
        if (ms <= 0)
        {
            action();
        }

        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            (o) => action(), 
            null, 
            ms, 
            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Now, I see that you are specifying the `period` argument of the timer's constructor as `System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite` (-1). What this means is that you intend for your timer to call `action` **once**, after `ms` has elapsed; am I right? If this is the case, then there's actually not much need to worry about the timer being disposed anyway (i.e., it will be, and that's fine), assuming a relatively low value for `ms`.

Anyway, if you're going to hold onto an instance of an `IDisposable` object (like `System.Threading.Timer`), you should generally dispose of that member when *your* object (i.e., this instance) is disposed of. I believe `System.Threading.Timer` has a finalizer that will cause it to be disposed of eventually anyway, but it's best to dispose of things as soon as you don't need them anymore. So:

```
public class Delayer : IDisposable
{
    // same code as above, plus...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid keeping a reference to the timer explicitly. The application reads a configuration of "Actions" from xml, Delay being a type of "Action". I don't want to have to root the "delayer" - but I'll have a bit more of a think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: Well, I didn't mean to suggest that you should write a new class called `Delayer`, but rather that whatever class *of which your `Delay` method is already a member* needs to hold on to the reference. That said, have you taken a look at my suggested alternative? I think it would exhibit the behavior you want without having to deal with the mess of maintaining and disposing of a timer.

Comment: Unforunately, using the Queue is not a guaranteed way to handle this because if the queue is full or delayed, then your delay is {the queue delay}+{your delay} which may or may not matter to you.

Comment: @JerryNixon: Indeed, it is less than a perfect solution. But can you think of a better way? It seems to me that if the thread pool is blocked, that's a straight-up problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: 99% of the time you are right. But in some instances you need to complete 1,000 operations and simply queue them up in the threadpool. Nothing wrong with that. That is why it exists. A better solution, if this case is possible in your app, is to create a new thread with a Thread.Sleep() to delay it. A full threadpool doesn't mean the sys is bogged, just that the pool is full.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach wouldn't keep the reference either. After the end of the Delay2-block, the reference to `state` is gone so the Garbage Collector will collect it ... then your reference to `Timer` is gone, too and it will be collected and disposed.

```
class MyClass
{
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    private void Delay(Action action, Int32 ms)   
    {   
        if (ms <= 0)   
        {   
            action();   
        }   

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(   
            (o) => action(),    
            null,    
            ms,    
            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that was intended; the timer only get's fired once. So long as the Timer gets referenced until it actually fires then that's good.

Comment: But you don't make sure it is kept until it's fired once, if the Garbage Collection is run after you left the Delay method but before the timer is fired, you timer will be collected and disposed!

Answer (score 1):

I read from your comments to the existing answers that you can have 0..n Actions and so you would have 0..n Timers, too. Is that right? In this case you should do one of the following:

1. Keep a List/Dictionary of timers, but in this case you have to remove the timer after firing.
2. Build a scheduler: have 1 Timer, that fired regulary, for each Delay-call add the action an the calculated time when it should run into a List/Dictionary, each time the timer fired, check you list and run&remove the Action. You can even build this scheduler that it sorts the Actions by execution time an sets the Timer to an adequate interval.

Answer (score 1):

The code "working" is indeed a side-effect of a *non-deterministic Garbage Collection / finalizers*.

This code, running in LINQ Pad as C# Statements, shows the issue - *no* messages will be logged because the Timer is GC'ed (and the finalizer is called and it cleans up the internal timer resources..)

```
new System.Threading.Timer((o) => { "Hi".Dump(); }, this, 100, 100);
GC.Collect();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

However, comment out the "GC.Collect" statement and messages will be logged for 2 seconds as Garbage Collection is not [immediately] performed the Timer's *finalizer* is not called prior to the program ending.

Since the behavior is *non-deterministic*, it should also be considered a bug to rely on :}

The same issue exists in the follow on code because a *strong reference* is required to ensure an object is not GC'ed - in that example, there is still no reference kept to the `timer` wrapper object so the same issue exists, albeit with one more level of indirection..