# Dynamic System.Timers.Timer and Garbage Collection?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I dynamically create a timer like this:

```
        System.Timers.Timer expirationTimer = new Timer(expiration * 60000);
        expirationTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => removeExpiredCacheEntry(sessionID);
        expirationTimer.Start();
```

When that reference goes out of scope, will the Timer object be garbage collected? If so, will the event still fire? If not, then how would I avoid a memory leak in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298276/134761), the timer object will indeed be eligible for garbage collection and cease to fire events at some point.

However, garbage collection is prevented the other way around. If we have

```
publisher.SomeEvent += target.SomeHandler;
```

then "publisher" will keep "target" alive, but "target" will not keep "publisher" alive.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have a concrete answer on this.

Answer (score 2):

Once the object goes out of scope, and there are no additional references to it.  It will, eventually, be garbage collected.  But this might not happen for a while.  So, the timer will likely keep firing until it is eventaully garbage collected.

This is just a guess though, as I don't have the ability to test it at the moment.

UPDATE:

I just wrote a small test program that looks something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetTimer();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void SetTimer()
{
    Timer expirationTimer = new Timer(1000);
    expirationTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Notify(e);
    expirationTimer.Start();
}

private static void Notify(ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Notified! {0}", e.SignalTime));   
}
```

The timer keeps firing for a long time (i eventually just ended the program).  Interestingly enough, i inserted a 15 second sleep in the main function, then called `GC.Collect()` and the timer kept running even after the forced garbage collection, although there is no guarantee that calling `GC.Collect()` will actually do anything.

I also tried wrapping the timer in a using statement, and that correctly disabled the timer right away (did not print anything to the screen).  So, I believe my assumption is correct that garbage collection will eventually collect the timer, and dispose of it.  but there is no way to determine when that will be.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just passing the timer itself along to the event handler, which should keep it from being garbage collected and lets me directly call Dispose() on it.