# MVC code to see whether or not a Controller is still in use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I have a controller which creates an instance of a `Model` object. Within the `Model`, I have a timer which executes a function every `700ms`. When I run the controller within my website, I continue to see the timer running even after I close the browser window. (The timer starts/stops a serial port connection, and I have a light that indicates when there is communication).

The communication actually never stops until I restart IIS entirely.

Is there some way in which I can check whether the controller is still in use, and thereby stop the timer if the controller is no longer active?

Here is the model code:

```
public CheckPulses(int interval) {
    CheckPulsesTimer(interval);   
}

public void CheckPulsesTimer(int interval) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetPulses);
}
```

And here is the Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    CheckPulses Pulses = new CheckPulses(700);
    return View();
}
```

I thought perhaps I should just add something to the `GetPulses` event, which happens every time the timer interval expires, and check there whether the controller is still in use. If it isn't, stop the timer. However, I'm not sure how to write that check. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You start a timer but never stop it.  Is it any wonder it keeps running?  It doesn't miraculously stop just because you close your browser window.  The web server has no idea if the browser window is open or not.

Comment: Frankly you shouldn't be managing the lifetime of the timer based on the lifetime of the controller since its life time is an implementation detail of the framework.  Instead you need some client side javascript that tells the serial port controller that it is still alive and tear down the serial port connection when the client stops firing events.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the controller is no longer active"? Do you mean when the controller method is finished and it returns an ActionResult? Or do you mean when the user finally closes the webpage after they are finished looking at it?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the little checkbox beneath its score. If not, please let me know what further information you need, so I can help you more.

Answer (score 3):

I think the core issue here is in your understanding of what a controller being "in use" is.

It seems as if you are imagining the following:

1. The user types in your URL and the browser connects to the server.
2. The server routes the request to an MVC Controller, which keeps a connection to the browser, and responds to each subsequent request using this connection.
3. The user closes their browser, or navigates away - and the Controller closes down the connection, and disposes.

This is not, however, what actually happens. Web traffic is generally a series of isolated, individual request/response pairings. There is no ongoing connection between the browser and the server.

The more correct sequence is something like the following:

1. The user types in your URL, and the browser connects to your server on port 80 (or 443 for https), passing in a valid HTTP request, containing a URL, HTTP verb, and other info.
2. Your server uses the HTTP request's information to *route* the request to a specific piece of executable code (in this case, your `Controller`'s specific `Action` method).
3. In order to execute, the server creates an Instance of your `Controller`, then fires it's `Action` method, using the HTTP request's information as parameters.
4. Your `Controller` code executes, and an HTTP response message is sent back to the browser.
5. The `Controller` is `.Dispose()`'d by the `ControllerFactory`.

The issue you're experiencing is not caused by your `Controller` being "active" - because that's not something `Controller`s do. You are, instead, creating a `Timer` within your `Model` - and the `Model`, therefore, continues to live on in memory, unable to be killed by `GarbageCollection`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760447/dynamic-system-timers-timer-and-garbage-collection) for more details.

In essence, think of it like this:

Your `Controller` is acting as a factory. When you call its `Index` method, it's equivalent to telling the factory "produce 1 `Model`". Once the `Model` rolls out of the factory, the factory is free to shut down, turn off the lights, and send all the workers home (the `Controller` is `.Dispose()`'d).

The `Model`, however, lives on in memory. In most cases, the `Model` should probably die off due to `GarbageCollection` once it goes out of scope - but because you have an active `Timer` inside of it, something is preventing that process from executing - and so the `Model` continues to live in your server's memory, happily firing its code again and again on each timer expiration.

Note that this has *nothing* to do with whether or not the user is still on your web-site, or whether their browser is still open, etc. It has to do with the nature of variable scoping and `GarbageCollection` on your server. You have now started a process which will continue until told to stop.

**A potential solution:**

In order to fix this, you might consider the following:

1. Create your `Timer` inside of a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object. Something like:

   ```
   public static class ConnectionManager {
       private static bool initialized = false;
       private static DateTime lastStartedAt = DateTime.Now;

       private static Timer timer = null;

       private static void Initialize() {
           if (timer == null) {
               timer = new Timer() {
                   AutoReset = true,
               };
               timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(GetPulses);
           }
       }

       public static void Start(int interval) {
           lastStartedAt = DateTime.Now;
           Initialize(); // Create a timer if necessary.
           timer.Enabled = true;
           timer.Interval = interval;
       }
       public static void Stop() {
           timer.Enabled = false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change your `Controller` to something like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index() {
       ConnectionManager.Start(700);
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. When you handle the expiration of the `Timer` event, check to see how long ago the `lastStartedAt` event occurred. If it is more than `X` minutes, do not process, and fire `ConnectionManager.Stop()`.

This will give you the ability to keep your serial activity polling on a rolling expiration. In other words - each time a user requests your `Index` page, you will refresh the timer, and ensure that you are listening. After `X` minutes, though, if no users have made a request - you can simply shut down the timer and the associated port.

Comment: Great explanation of the disconnected nature of web applications.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely not stopping or disposing the Timer. This will cause it to not be garbage collected and stay active for the duration the application stays running.

You should stop and dispose of the Timer within the Controller's Dispose method.

Comment: The question is how to check if a controller is in use not how to stop a timer and call dispose.

Comment: although it might be the way of solving my issue for my problem.. how do i use the dispose method and where should the method be input?

Comment: +1 I had a similar issue with an unmanaged resource (DirectorySearcher) that is used multiple times and so is not wrapped in a 'using' block. Not being an front-end developer, I had no idea that the Controller had an overridable Dispose(bool) method, and what's more, the documentation says it is called by the MVC framework on Request completion. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Override Dispose method on the controller and dispose your model with calling **Pulses.Dispose()**
2. Override OnActionExecuted method on the controller and do disposing
3. Create custom action filter and implement **OnActionExecuted** method and assign it to controller or action.(You can place reference to your model into TempData and then in your ActionFilter check if **filterContext.Controller.TempData["MyReferenceToModel"] != null**, then use it to dispose timer)
4. Implement IDisposable interface in your Model and use it inside using statement

Hope this helps,
Dima

Answer (score -3):

You can stop the Timer with JQuery+ MVC.

Jquery can respond to the unload event of the page like so:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

You can make ajax calls to your controllers. We also need to create a property to access the timer. I'll assume you called your Timer Property MyTimer

```
Timer MyTimer { get; set; }
```

So you need to create a controller that returns void and calls the Stop() method of your Timer. 
[HttpPost]
public void KillTimer()
{
    MyTimer.Stop();
}

Now if you add an Ajax call to your unload event we created earlier, then we should be able to kill the timer whenever the page closes.

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "POST",
   url: "/Home/Index",
   ,
   success: function(result)
    {
        alert("Timer Closed");
    },                
   error : function(req, status, error)
   {
        alert("Sorry! We could not receive your feedback at this time.");   
   }
});
```

The success and error functions are not necessary. I included them only for demonstration.
I also guessed the name of your controller to be Home. You will need to update the URL if it is something different. You could do this with pure javascript. JQuery helps to save you from writing lots of tedious browser compatibility code. (I hear opera is a pain with the unload part)

To address the issue of potential browser crashes and unexpected events you can wire up your controller to check if the timer has exceeded a max time limit.

Good Luck !

Sources :

[JQuery Unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

[Invoking ASP.NET MVC Actions from JavaScript using jQuery](http://iridescence.no/post/Invoking-ASPNET-MVC-Actions-from-JavaScript-using-jQuery.aspx)

[JQuery Ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: For a system resource like that, this is a very dangerous way to go about it.  IF the users browser crashes, for instance.. or their internet drops out and they close the browser.. the resource will not get released.  It also won't work in a non-javascript enabled browser.

Comment: A client-side answer is no solution to this server-side issue.

Comment: This is not 2005. Non-javascript browser are fading to a point of obscurity. The web is a javascript world. This is my opinion but a supported one. @Chris There were no requirements for this to not be a client side solution.