# Will this be G-Collected? C# events

Tags: c#, .net, events, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have some objects which have public events that objects 'listen' to to get messages pass through the system. The problem is my programs memory footprint keeps growing and I am wondering whether the GC is failing to collect the objects because other objects are subscribed to it's events

```
call.requestingHangup+=new CallEventHandler (Call_requestingHangup);
```

now if nothing else a named reference to this 'Call' however we are still subscribed to its event will the GC remove it. Also are there any memory diagnositic tools for c# like valgrind for native code?

Thank You

Comment: If something is using an object, it will not be subject to GC.

Comment: For memory diagnostic tools, you can try the free CLR Profiler from MS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx) or JetBrains dotTrace which is a paid application (http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

Comment: @ChrisBint It isn't using it, it is just listening to the event. In the above example Call will fall out of scope eventually. My question i guess if handlers are not explicitly will the object persist. Thanks

Comment: No, your `call` object is holding a reference, not being referenced. So it is not kept from being collected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do event handlers stop garbage collection from occuring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring

Comment: Henk: that was my thought it seems odd to me but the program keeps growing in size whilst have only a small range of active objects.

Comment: @1111: There are other places to get it wrong. But a growing footprint is not always a problem, so _how_ do you measure memory?  I don't think you have a leak.

Answer (score 0):

You should also de hook your events like below, when you are finished with them. This will make sure that they are GCed.

```
call.requestingHangup-=new CallEventHandler (Call_requestingHangup);
```

Please see [other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring) which explains this better.

Comment: No, this is not necessary in this case. It is the right code for un-hooking though, although a bit long. `-=Call_requestingHangup` is enough.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, it may not be necessary but is a good practice to get into. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid link, and comment Scott Langham made on "Common programming mistakes for .NET developers to avoid?"

Comment: The necessity depends entirely on the circumstances. We can't tell if that's the case in this question. But I strongly reject unsubscribing events everywhere.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, would it not be better to unsubscribe events when you are finished with them? Why do you strongly reject it?

Comment: It leads to the same cluttering as `myLocalRef = null` everywhere. It is rarely necessary and should be used only when it is.

Comment: But myLocalRef gets collected by the GC, does the GC know to do the same with the event? Would it not be better to -= (un hook) the event when you are done?