# Do I need to keep a reference to a FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, filesystemwatcher

I'm using a `FileSystemWatcher` (in an ASP.NET web app) to monitor a file for changes. The watcher is set up in the constructor of a Singleton class, e.g:

```
private SingletonConstructor()
{
    var fileToWatch = "{absolute path to file}";
    var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(fileToWatch),
        Path.GetFileName(fileToWatch));
    fsw.Changed += OnFileChanged;
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // process file...
}
```

Everything works fine so far. But my question is:

Is it safe to setup the watcher using a local variable (`var fsw`)? Or should I keep a reference to it in a private field to prevent it from being garbage collected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the example above `FileSystemWatcher` is kept alive only because the property `EnableRaisingEvents` is set to `true`.  The fact that the Singleton  class has an event handler registered to `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event does not  have any direct bearing on `fsw` being eligible for Garbage collection. See [Do event handlers stop garbage collection from occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring) for more information.

The following code shows that with `EnableRaisingEvents`  set to `false`, the `FileSystemWatcher` object is garbage collected: Once `GC.Collect()` is called, the `IsAlive` property on the `WeakReference` is `false`.

```
class MyClass
{
    public WeakReference FileSystemWatcherWeakReference;
    public MyClass()
    {
        var fileToWatch = @"d:\temp\test.txt";
        var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(fileToWatch),
            Path.GetFileName(fileToWatch));
        fsw.Changed += OnFileChanged;
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        FileSystemWatcherWeakReference = new WeakReference(fsw);
    }

    private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // process file... 
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine(mc.FileSystemWatcherWeakReference.IsAlive);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can find no documentation to say that `EnableRaisingEvents` has any effect on the garbage collection. I thought a local field was needed to ensure the `FileSystemWatcher` wasn't garbage collected.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example that shows FileSystemWatcher is garbage collected if EnableRaisingEvents is false.

Comment: Thanks for that, I do wish that functionality was documented on the MSDN, it looks like it would be too easy to end up with some hanging `FileSystemWatcher`s.

Comment: Thank you Muath for your beautiful answer. However, could you please explain why when "EnableRaisingEvents is set to true" the object is not collected by GC?