# Why can't the instance bound to an event be collected by the GC?

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection

This Question based on this question:
[How to dispose the local variable that contains event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992100/how-to-dispose-the-local-variable-that-contains-event)

Someone said:one event handler to an instance,the reference count of the instance will added? why?

Comment: see this thread, it may be a help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506092/is-it-necessary-to-explicitly-remove-event-handlers-in-c-sharp

Comment: That answer is wrong, basically - the answerer has his concepts the wrong way round. I've added a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked question, as Jon Skeet states, has it backwards. The only thing keeping `watcher` alive is perhaps its own internal implementation where it may (or may not) register an event with a lower-level object that is responsible for feeding back "ticks". -but this is just conjecture.

Clicking the button twice will yield two **separate** `watcher` instances, each with **one** subscriber to the `PositionChanged` event (which just happens to be the same method on the same instance).

Importantly, it **isn't** the `PositionChanged` subscriber that is keeping `watcher` alive after the method quits - it is something else (I suspect buried within the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` implementation). When the method exits, a reference to a particular instance of `watcher` is *correctly* popped off the stack, but due to *another* reference being held on `watcher` the effective reference count in the eyes of the CLR is still greater than zero - therefore, ***not*** eligible for garbage collection.

Because of this, it will continue on to fire the `PositionChanged` event. As nothing in the event stops the watcher from continuing, I'm going to guess you may have a memory leak because each button click will create and **leave alive** a watcher instance.

You either need to store and use only one `GeoCoordinateWatcher` class, or close-off / dispose / stop it each time you handle the event.

---

The usual consideration with events and subscriptions is being mindful of short-lived objects subscribing to long-lived objects.

Delegates hold references to a particular method in a particular instance of a class (or just the type itself if it were a static method). Subscribing to an event causes the event publisher to inadvertently hold a reference to the subscriber instance via the subscription's delegate.

Obviously, if you register a static method as an event handler, you won't get this reference count because there is no instance.

A memory leak can occur if the subscriber is short-lived and the event publisher is long-lived, if you don't unsubscribe. Assume the subscriber would like to be eligible for GC, because it has an active subscription against an event somewhere and *that* object still lives, it cannot be eligible until it is removed from that subscription list.

Comment: THat's all correct, but isn't what the OP was asking about - the referenced answer talks about the event handler keeping the *publisher* alive, which is incorrect.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, caught red-handed not really reading the linked question. I'll remove this.

Comment: Scratch that, I read the other question and amended my answer instead.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thank you very much! I decompiled the GeoCoordinateWatcher Class and I found that the Start() method will add himself to ThreadPool,so it won't collected by the GC!

Comment: @Dozer No problem, glad you found the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Cause by calling [GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808853.aspx) you start a new *task*. Even if it declared in *your* code like a `local` variable, it will continue live after the exit of the scope of the function.

You can think about this, like if you start a 3rd part `process` from the function. Function's scope gone, but the process still live.

In the link provided, if you click button twice, this will lead 2 different instances of the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` be handled by the **same** event handler.  So that event handler will be invoked twice from 2 diffrent instances of `GeoCoordinateWatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a delegate object, it contains the `Method` and `Target` properties. The [Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target) property points to the object whose context the `Target` method will be called in (first parameter, aka `this`).

Under certain circumstances, the reference to the delegate object will be active, hence preventing the `Target` instance from being GCed. It usually happens when you have a plugin/addin-based application, or some other sort of late-bound situation, or you're doing a lot of work with delegates and delegate objects are stored in some collection, or you have a static field with a delegate object, (since static fields are never collected) etc.

Keep in mind that garbage collection is not susceptible to the "circular reference" problem; for an object to be deemed "useful", it has to be reachable from the current stack.