# Why is my FileSystem Watcher not firing events?

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher

I create a FileSystemWatcher on a separate thread to monitor a directory for changes.  None of my events fire when I add a new file or copy a new file into the directory that I am trying to monitor.  I've used the FileSystemWatcher class successfully in Windows Forms apps, so I am guessing I am missing something simple.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(MonitorDir);
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void MonitorDir()
    {

        watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Temp","*.*");
        watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
        watcher.Disposed += Watcher_Disposed;
        watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
        watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }

    private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Watcher_Error(object sender, System.IO.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Watcher_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Watcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileSystemWatcher not firing events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278783/filesystemwatcher-not-firing-events)

Comment: Hello there! I haven't gotten any feedback from you, have you managed to solve your problem yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set its [**`EnableRaisingEvents` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` (it's `false` by default), otherwise it won't raise any events.

```
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Solved my problem.  :)

Comment: @BillGreer : Glad I could help! Good luck! ;)