# FileSystemWatcher doesn't trigger if the file is changed from solution explorer indeed it triggers from file explorer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, filesystemwatcher, file-watcher

I am facing a strange issue with FileSystemWatcher. The folder am watching is "publishing". The file am watching is "settings.json" which is in publishing folder inside one project

Problem : When settings.json is changed inside visual studio 2019 the event is not triggered but the file is saved, When settings.json is changed outside of visual studio i.e in file explorer the event is triggered and then the file is saved.

Any solution or alternatives of using FileSystemWatcher?

```
            FileSystemWatcher publishWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(DestinationDirectory + "\\publishing")
            {
                Filter = "settings.json"
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
            publishWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(PublishPackageChanged);

          private void PublishPackageChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
          {
          }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278783/filesystemwatcher-not-firing-events

Comment: Based on my test, I have reproduced your problem. This problem may be an issue. You can report it in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: Apart from the `Changed`, have you tried subscribing to the `Created` event as well?

Answer (score 0):

Some advice to try to find the error:

- Instead of DestinationDirectory + "\publishing", use "Path.Combine".
- Check that "DestinationDirectory" is the absolute path of the folder. You can use "Path.GetFullPath".
- Start trying to filter json files in general. I mean: Filter = "*.json"

Hope it helps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35048255)