# Does `Control.Dispose()` remove all event registrations?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, dispose

When I call `Dispose()` on a `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, does it automatically remove all event registrations?

So for example, is the following sufficient:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Click += someObject.clickHandler;
// ...
button.Dispose();
```

Or do I need to unregister the event handler explicitly, like this:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Click += someObject.clickHandler;
// ...
button.Click -= someObject.clickHandler;
button.Dispose();
```

Comment: Annoyingly, the model that `Component` (and therefore `Control`) use for most of their events (via `EventHandlerList`) would actually have made this very achievable. It is interesting that they chose not to do this; all they would have to do is set the `events` field to `null` at the end of `Dispose(bool disposing)`

Comment: Yeah I saw the `EventHandlerList` field in `Component` and was therefore kind of expecting that they use it in `Dispose(bool)` to unsubscribe all event handlers - but it isn't mentioned in the documentation, that's why I had to ask here... Annoying indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, It doesn't. You ought to remove the handlers yourself. Simple test can prove that.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    var button = new Button();
    button.Click += button_Click;

    //Some code
    button.Dispose();
    button.PerformClick();//Simulate a click event
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Oops! Still alive?");
}
```

Run the above code, You'll see MessageBox popping up saying "Oops! Still alive?" which means handlers are *not removed* even when we `Dispose` the `Control`.

Refer [Marc's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring) to see how this can affect Garbage collection.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Dispose()` does not explicitly remove event handlers, but it does result in those events no longer being sent. When the garbage collector reclaims the memory from `button`, the even registrations will be finally removed.

The more important situation to consider is when `button` is listing for events from other objects:

```
var button = new Button();
otherObject.SomeEvent += button.HandleSomeEvent;
// ...
button.Dispose();
```

In this case, the registered event handler can actually prevent `button` from getting garbage collected. If this situation applies to your code, you'll need to either remove the relevant event listeners in the `Dispose()` method, or use a weak event listener pattern to allow the garbage collector to clean up those handlers.