# Must a form remove all event handlers when closing/disposing?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I stumbled over this code snippet at [How to remove all event handlers from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control/5475424#5475424) :

```
void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Delegate d in FindClicked.GetInvocationList())
    {
        FindClicked -= (FindClickedHandler)d;
    }
}
```

My question is: assuming that the form is about to be disposed (after being closed), would the snippet be required or would `FindClicked` and all references to event handler delegates simply go down with the form when it is GC´ed (which the referenced event handlers shouldn't cause any problems with)?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation suggests that you should remove all event handlers when disposing:

> [In order to prevent resource leaks, you should unsubscribe from events before you dispose of a subscriber object.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#unsubscribing)

You can also check out this other answer, which might be useful: [Does `Control.Dispose()` remove all event registrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934267/does-control-dispose-remove-all-event-registrations)

Comment: thanks for the ultra-fast response. why did you edit the link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934267/does-control-dispose-remove-all-event-registrations helped me a whole lot more!

Comment: @mike You're welcome, I edited the link because it was pointing to the wrong source for my quote. The Microsoft documentation seemed more authoritative. I've re-added the link to the other question for anyone else who may find that post useful.