# WPF - Remove event handler from frozen animation object

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
AddHandler aX.Completed, AddressOf AnimationCompleted

...

Private Sub AnimationCompleted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

      Dim ac As AnimationClock = sender
      Dim aX As DoubleAnimationUsingPath = ac.Timeline

      RemoveHandler aX.Completed, AddressOf AnimationCompleted

End Sub
```

Throws:

> Specified value of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimationUsingPath' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify.

How can I remove the event handler if the object is frozen? My concern is that if the event handler is not removed the animation object will not be properly garbage collected.

Comment: Removing the event handler is not necessary. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/298276/1136211).

Comment: Is this the case in WPF? I know there are instances in WPF if you don't remove the event handler of a control then the control is not removed even though it is no longer in the Window.

Comment: We're talking about a regular .NET event here, so the answer should be applicable.