# Control the release of an instance in C#

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

**I understand that C# use garbage collector** to manage all the managed resources, when an instance are no longer referenced, GC may collect them.

But my question is: is there any good practice to properly remove those references?

Let's say **we bought a Zoo**, in this zoo we have **1 tiger** and **1 alarm**

```
public class Zoo
{
    public static Action OpenZoo;
    public Tiger tiger1 = new Tiger();
}
```

Tiger subscribed to `OpenZoo` event and will make sound when zoo opens

```
public class Tiger
{
    public Tiger()
    {
        Zoo.OpenZoo += Meow;
    }
    private void Meow() { }
}
```

One day we want to get rid of the tiger, to my understanding we **CANNOT** simply do

```
tiger1 = null
```

we have to make the tiger to unsubscribe to the alarm first, then null the tiger1 and hope gc kicks in or call CG.collect.

```
Zoo.OpenZoo -= Meow;
tiger1 = null
```

in this example there it's not that hard, but imagine we have multiple object subscribe to multiple event, getting referenced by multiple objects etc.

what if this tiger1 subscribed to all the youtube channel in the world, if we need to get rid of this tiger, we have to unsubscribe all the youtube channel all over again? how can you so sure you didn't missed one?

**So my question is:**

**Are there any better ways to manage such situation?**

Comment: I'm not sure if the Tiger should have access to the zoo. Maybe it should be the other way round

Comment: Assuming you cannot change the design as proposed in the above comment, you probably want to use [`WeakReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references)

Comment: If the class that needs to be removed uses resource and, possibly, subscribes to events, let it implement `IDisposable` and dispose of the managed objects it references and unwire the events when you `Dispose()` of it. A Tiger shouldn't be allowed to open the Zoo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do event handlers stop garbage collection from occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occurring)