# .NET Events calling back once callee goes out of scope: safe practice?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

(apologies if this has come up before, I've searched but not found anything for my search terms)

Given the following:

```
void Method1 {
    Foo _foo = new Foo();
    _foo.DataReady += ProcessData();
    _foo.StartProcessingData();
}

void ProcessData() { //do something }
```

`StartProcessingData()` is a long running method which eventually (*and asynchronously*) raises the `DataReady` event. (let's say it does a service call or something)

Now, `_foo` used to be a class-level variable, and the event used to be wired up in the constructor.

However, memory profiling highlighted how this would keep `_foo` and all its dependents in memory forever, hence my change to the above.

My question is: is there ever a case when the GC will ruin things? `Method1` finishes quickly (and certainly before the event fires), which means that `_foo` ceases to be. However, does this mean that (because _foo keeps the references for its events) `ProcessData()` will never fire? Or, is the presence of the event enough to keep _foo alive past the end of the method just enough to ensure that ProcessData fires? Or is it inconclusive?

[In testing, it's worked fine - `ProcessData` is always called. Even making `StartProcessingData` take a long time, and forcing a GC collection mid-way through (using RedGate's Memory Profiler) didn't remove it. But I'd like to be sure!]

For clarification: `StartProcessingData()` returns immediately. The `Foo` object would be something like:

```
class Foo
{
SomeSerice _service;
event EventHandler<EventArgs> DataReady;

Foo()
{
_service = new SomeService();
_service.ServiceCallCompleted += _service_ServiceCallCompleted;
}

void StartProcessingData()
{
_service.ServiceCallAsync();
}

void _service_ServiceCallCompleted
{
DataReady(null,e);
}
```

So, something that abstracts and emulates a long-running, asynchronous service using events to signal significant, uh, events.

---

Here's a complete, working example (a console app)

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Class1 _class1 = new Class1();
                Console.WriteLine("Disposing of Class 1");
                _class1 = null;

                GC.Collect();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
                Console.Read();

            }

        }

        internal class Class1
        {
            internal Class1()
            {
                Foo _foo = new Foo();
                _foo.DataReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(_foo_DataReady);

                _foo.StartProcessingData();
            }

            void _foo_DataReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class 1 Processing Data");
            }
        }

        class Foo
        {
            internal event EventHandler<EventArgs> DataReady = delegate { };

            internal void StartProcessingData()
            {
                System.Threading.Timer _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimer);

                Console.WriteLine("Firing event in 10 secs");
                _timer.Change(10000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            }

            private void OnTimer(object state)
            {
                DataReady(this, null);
            }
    }
```

If you run it, you'll get:

```
Firing event in 10 secs
Disposing of Class 1
Class 1 Processing Data
```

Comment: Is it a typo that StartProcessingData is static? Or did you mean to put _foo.StartProcessingData()

Comment: yeah, it was a typo. fixed now: thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you completely. I assume that `StartProcessingData` will actually invoke the handler. If that is the case then `Method1` will not finish before this call is completed as the code is now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make clear that StartProcessingData would asynchronously raise the event. I'll edit the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that `StartProcessingData()` is entirely synchronous (i.e. threading is not involved). It will not return until after the event fires, and `ProcessData()` will be called from *within* `_foo.StartProcessingData()`. If you want to verify this, put a breakpoint in `ProcessData()` and look at the call stack.

So, that being said, `_foo` won't be out of scope when the event is fired and the handler is called, because `Method1()` has not returned.

Now, if threading *is* involved, that means the code executing in the other thread must be holding a reference to `_foo`; otherwise, it would be impossible for the event to be fired. Therefore, `_foo` is still not a candidate for garbage collection.  So, in either case, you shouldn't need to be concerned about `_foo` getting garbage collected.

**(edit)**

Hooking the `ServiceCallCompleted` event of `_service` now means that `_service` holds a reference to `_foo`, preventing it from being garbage collected.

Comment: What happens in the period of time once `StartProcessingData()` finishes, before the event is raised, and when `_foo` doesn't exist? I had originally assumed that the event just wouldn't be raised, as it's sort of not there any more, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: If `StartProcessingData()` is synchronous, you are misunderstanding the order of execution; `StartProcessingData()` won't return until after the event is fired.  If threading is involved, the other thread is holding a reference to `_foo` and preventing it from being garbage collected.  It might help to post the code to your `Foo` object.

Comment: StartProcessingData will return immediately. I will post some pseduo code for the Foo object. To take what both of you said: this is why I'm confused. _foo keeps the reference to the callback (not the other way around), so there's nothing that stops _foo being GC'd. And once the method finishes it goes out of scope. But yet, the event still fires OK.

Comment: If StartProcessingData() returns immediately, then there's threading going on, right?  If so, then the other thread has a reference to _foo, which keeps _foo alive.

Comment: I always get my head turned a little when it comes to garbage collection. I had originally thought that what FMM was correct, but then found the following SO question and thought the opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring However, I then followed the sublink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185931/weakreference-and-event-handling Which had a reference to http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx .... which, turned me all the way back to my original assumption that is the same as FMM

Comment: In conclusion, FMM is correct, but I highly suggest reading through the links I provided to get a stronger understanding of GC and events. As they can be quite dangerous if not understood properly

Comment: I certainly will be reading up!! I've just posted a working example in the original question to show what's happening.  I'm confused because _foo keeps a reference to the method that gets called on return, not the other way around. In my example, _foo, and _timer are created by _class1. But _class1 is removed, destroyed and not there by the time the timer fires. But, the event is raised anyway.

I think FMM's edit explains it in a nutshell: "Hooking the ServiceCallCompleted event of _service now means that _service holds a reference to _foo, preventing it from being garbage collected." ...

Comment: ...and in my example, hooking the DataReady event of _foo means that _foo holds a reference to _class1, preventing it from being garbage collected. In fact, preventing it from being set to null at all? Meh, need to read more!

Comment: Thanks to you both for your extensive brain-time and explanations! Justin, mind if I mark this as answer, but will +v you also?

Comment: I deleted my wrong responses to avoid future confusion. Feel free to +1 my comment if it helped at all though :)

Comment: Great discussion here, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for an object `Foo` to subscribe to events from object `Bar` and then abandon all references to `Bar` without, in most cases, affecting `Bar`'s ability to fire events, since `Bar` would presumably have its events triggered as a result of some thread or outside object, which could only happen if that thread or outside object had a reference to it.  There are two reasons it could be important `Foo` keeps a reference to `Bar`; it's possible neither applies in your case.

1. If `Foo` does not keep any reference to `Bar`, it may be unable to let `Bar` know if it later finds itself with no need for `Bar`'s services.  It could try using the `Sender` parameter of some later event callback to unsubscribe, but there are at least two problems with that: (1) Sometimes an object will raise events on behalf of another, in which case the `Sender` property might not identify the object holding the event subscription; (2) It's possible that the event might never get raised, but the reference to the subscriber could prevent the subscriber from being eligible for garbage-collection until the publisher is.

   It's possible (albeit unlikely) that the only other references to `Bar`, anywhere in the system, might be `WeakReference` types, and thus if `Foo` doesn't keep a strong reference to `Bar`, the system might invalidate all those weak references, effectively causing `Bar` to disappear.

Personally I believe it's a good idea for objects to cancel all subscriptions before they are abandoned.  One may expect that an event publisher will go out of scope around the time a subscriber is abandoned, but if events are left connected anything which keeps a publisher alive will uselessly keep abandoned subscribers alive.  If any of those abandoned subscribers are also event publishers, their abandoned subscribers in turn may be kept alive uselessly, etc.